# Map<string, enum> is not assignable to type { [key: string]: enum }'. Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, enum>'

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
export enum Relationship {}

export interface Invitee {}

export interface InviteesResponse {
    invitees: Invitee[];
    relationships: { [key: string]: Relationship }; // map userIds to relationships
}



async getInvitees(userId: string): Promise<InviteesResponse> {
...
        const invitees: Invitee[] = [];
        const relationships: Map<string, Relationship> = new Map();
...
        // this line throws the error on relationships
        return { invitees, relationships };
```

Webstorm suggests the following fix:

```
async getInvitees(userId: string): Promise<{ invitees: Invitee[]; relationships: Map<string, Relationship> }> {
```

I guess I just don't understand the core issue. Why is it forcing me to destructure the type just to return?

And here's the full-ish error again:

```
Type 'Map<string, Relationship>' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: Relationship; }'.   Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, Relationship>'.
```

Comment: A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) has its own methods to get and set data; you don't use it like a plain object with property keys/values.  See [Objects vs Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps).  The type of `relationships` is declared as a plain object with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) but you initialized it with a `Map`, which is something else entirely.  Do you understand now?

Comment: If so I could maybe write up an answer.  Otherwise please elaborate on what the disconnect is and maybe I can rephrase...

Comment: I figured it out - turns out my typescript syntax was just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was simple.    `relationships: { [key: string]: Relationship };` is not the correct syntax for a map.

It should be: `relationships: Map<string, Relationship>;`

I don't know why I thought that maps didn't have a an explicit typescript type but they do so everything is good now!